# How flexible is my Schengen multi-entry visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, chinese-citizens

I am Chinese and I have a UK spouse residence visa. I recently applied to the Netherlands visa office for a Schengen visa to visit Holland, this visit is only for two days. They then issued me with a 6 months multi-entry visa. I wish to visit Spain for 2 weeks in December, can I use the visa for this trip?

Comment: Yes, it should be no problem. It's not unusual for them to do that as UK residents are considered low risk so they might as well save themselves some paperwork.